# How to add check box and image to react-select options?

Tags: image, checkbox, react-select

Could someone help me with, how to add checkbox and image in react-select dropdown, like in the given image?

[image]

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to overwrite component as specified in the following [documentation](https://react-select.com/components#components). Here an example:

```
const Option = props => {
  return (components.Option && <components.Option {...props}>
    <Image/>{props.data.label}<Checkbox/>
  <components.Option/>)
}
```

For the image source you can add it into your select options data and access it with `props.data`